# Wso2: Error while renewing Access Token for Consumer Key xxxx and user admin

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Stack trace for the error:

```
TID: [-1] [] [2016-12-15 10:44:26,663] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler}
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1800)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1083)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:907)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doUnwrap(SSLIOSession.java:245)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:280)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:410)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:119)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:159)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:338)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:316)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:277)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please let me know if any other configs are required for understanding.

Comment: How do you renew? Which component's log is this?

Comment: This is the log of gateway/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log. I am renewing using the store UI under Production Keys section after hitting the Re-generate tab.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you don't have keymanager's public certificate in gateway. Key manager's Public certificate should be installed to gateway's `client-truststore.jks` which is located in `<GW_HOME>/repository/resources/security/`.